# Implementing anti forgery validation for Blazor UI application

Tags: csrf, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

Our application is built using Blazor Server and .razor pages which communicates to Azure APIs. I would like to know if for Blazor UI should we implement Anti forgery CSRF/XSRF, if so can I get some information how to implement?

I have observed posts implementing Anti forgery for ASP .Net core MVC applications https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-anti-forgery-tokens-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/ and also blogs mentioned that Razor pages implement Anti forgery validation by default.

But for Blazor would like to know what is the pattern to follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/threat-mitigation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cross-origin-protection):

> Blazor Server apps can be accessed cross-origin unless additional
> measures are taken to prevent it. To disable cross-origin access,
> either disable CORS in the endpoint by adding the CORS middleware to
> the pipeline and adding the DisableCorsAttribute to the Blazor
> endpoint metadata or limit the set of allowed origins by configuring
> SignalR for cross-origin resource sharing.
>
> If CORS is enabled, extra steps might be required to protect the app
> depending on the CORS configuration. If CORS is globally enabled, CORS
> can be disabled for the Blazor Server hub by adding the
> DisableCorsAttribute metadata to the endpoint metadata after calling
> MapBlazorHub on the endpoint route builder.