# "The antiforgery token could not be decrypted" on second request from Blazor webassembly page

Tags: asp.net-core, csrf, blazor-webassembly

I have ASP.NET MVC Core application with Blazor webassembly "islands".
I set up CSRF token protection based on following manual https://remibou.github.io/CSRF-protection-with-ASPNET-Core-and-Blazor-Week-29/

First POST request from page works fine, but second always fails with

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter[1]
      Antiforgery token validation failed. The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
       ---> System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters
```

How I can debug and diagnose this?

Comment: You probably looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404877/implementing-anti-forgery-validation-for-blazor-ui-application). The details you can get from [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0)